# Set the parent of an Aurelia Dialog

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

Aurelia Dialog puts all the UI elements for itself at the root of the document (or very near).

**Is there a way to configure where the dialog places itself in the document?**

(I am trying to make the dialog be part of my router page rather than part of the overall document.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, as stated by the official doc: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/dialog/latest/dialog-basics/5

In the controller settings part, there is a config property name `host`, which you can pass an element here to be anchor for the dialog, instead of the default `document.body`

---

doc:

`host`: allows providing the element which will parent the dialog - if not provided the body will be used.

Comment: I did not know that Aurelia Dialog was in the docs!  Thank you!